# How do I scroll an overflowed div to a certain hashtag (anchor)?

Tags: javascript, anchor, hashtag

On my webpage I have an overflowed div (i.e. with the vertical scrollbar). Inside the div, I have anchors with ids. When I put one of these ids in the URL (mypage.html#id), I want the div, not the page, to scroll to that anchor.

How do I do that, preferably with plain JavaScript? If it's too complex, I'll go with jQuery, but I'm not using it in this project for anything else.

Comment: So all 3 of these answers work, thanks. I still have to do cross-browser testing, but for now I went with .focus()

Comment: So testing in multiple browses has shown that only .scrollTop() works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('.overflow').scrollTop($('#anchor').offset().top);
```

There is no reason at all you can't convert this to standard javascript.

Note that the scroll will be off if there is a margin on the anchor element.

Comment: I had to reorganize my HTML and CSS a bit but this works (with .position(), not .offset()). I looked at jQuery source and ripping these methods out might be a bit difficult. I'll try and post pure javascript if I'll succeed.

Comment: There are too many interdependencies in jQuery to rip this out. What the hell, I'll go with this solution - I just realized that for the next feature I'd be using jQuery anyway. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Actually, I'll go with the simpler solution with focus(), just tested it.

Comment: I was not expecting you to actually rewrite JQuery. Those properties I used are standard javascript ones. Just lookup how to change and read the offset and position, and do it directly. (They have different names sometimes in different browsers.)

Comment: This is a very poor solution that works only when a multitude of extra assumptions are met. Margins, paddings, elements with position: relative in the parent-child hierarchy between the anchor and the div - most combinations of these will break this method.

The only reliable way is to compute **document-absolute** vertical positions of the div and the anchor and set scrollTop to their difference. Reliably computing document-absolute positions is **fantastically hard**. Plugins that handle this tend to check DOZENS of special cases for EACH parent-child pair on path from <html> to the element.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to set `focus()` on the anchor?

Any DOM element with a tabindex is focusable, and any element which has focus will be scrolled into view by the browser.

Answer (score 4):

This is a pure Javascript (ECMA 6) solution, similar to Ariel's answer.

```
const overflow = document.querySelector('.overflow');
const anchor = document.getElementById('anchor');

// Get the bounding client rectangles for both
// the overflow container and the target anchor
const rectOverflow = overflow.getBoundingClientRect();
const rectAnchor = anchor.getBoundingClientRect();

// Set the scroll position of the overflow container
overflow.scrollTop = rectAnchor.top - rectOverflow.top;
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you in nearly any major browser in 2021, use `element.scrollIntoView()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

> The Element interface's scrollIntoView() method scrolls the element's
> parent container such that the element on which scrollIntoView() is
> called is visible to the user - **MDN Web Docs**

Example:

```
var myEl = document.getElementById("child");
myEl.scrollIntoView()
```

or with **[Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#parameters)** -- Not supported in Safari or Internet Explorer:

```
myEl.scrollIntoView({
    block: "center" // Start, center, end, or nearest. Defaults to start.
    behavior: "smooth"
})
```